# When does a self retain a closure?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I have been reading in memory management for a while and I knew that when the closure retains self and self retains closure we should put [weak self] to break the cycle, my question is when does the closure retain self and when does self retain a closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *usually* pretty obvious, though not always.

- The closure retains `thing` if it mentions `thing` or any property of `thing`.
- `thing` retains the closure if it has a property that is or contains a function and that function is the closure.

The artificial example I use in my book is:

```
class FunctionHolder {
    var function : (() -> ())?
}
func testFunctionHolder() {
    let fh = FunctionHolder()
    fh.function = {
        print(fh)
    }
}
```

Here, `thing` is `fh`, a FunctionHolder instance. We assign to the `function` property of `fh` a closure that mentions `fh`. That's a retain cycle.

The problem in real life is that this happens without your realizing it. You know you're retaining *something*, but you might not realize that the something is or contains a closure. The classic example is when you call

```
let ob = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:...
```

That call returns an observer object, which you retain so that you will get notifications. But you also hand that call a closure, and if it mentions you, you've got a retain cycle, because you are retaining the observer which contains the closure which mentions you.

And there are a number of other common pitfall situations of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var data = Data() {
        didSet {
            // do something
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Service.loadData { data in
            self.data = data
        }
        perform(#selector(tryToDismiss), with: self, afterDelay: 0.5)
    }

    @objc func tryToDismiss() {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    deinit {
        print("ViewController got deinit")
    }
}

class Service {

    static func loadData(completion: @escaping (Data) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            completion(Data())
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that even though the view controller is getting dismissed after 0.5 seconds of getting loaded it's not getting deinitialized because of the closure that completes the load data after 1 second.